# Можно ли обращаться к атрибутам экземпляра в метаклассе?

Tags: python, metaclass

Вопрос не ради решения какой-то задачи, а просто для понимания.
Тестирую всё на таком примере кода:

```
class MetaUpdate(type):
    def __new__(cls, clsname, bases, attrs):
        update_attrs = {
            attrs if attrs.startswith('__') else attrs.upper(): v for attrs, v in attrs.items()
        }
  
        return super(MetaUpdate, cls).__new__(
            cls, clsname, bases, update_attrs
        )

class MyClass(metaclass = MetaUpdate):
    # С атрибутом класса работает 
    correct = 'Меня видно'
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        # С атрибутом экземпляра не работает 
        self.wrong = 'Меня не видно внутри Meta'

a = MyClass()
print(dir(a)) # CORRECT, ......, wrong
```

Стало интересно. Можно ли обратиться к атрибутам экземпляра внутри метакласса или это технически невозможно из-за того, что `__new__` срабатывает перед `__init__` и методов атрибута ещё нет?

Comment: Если я вас правильно понял, то да, `__init__` срабатывает позже, чем `__new__`, поэтому то, что вы делаете в `__new__` не влияет на те атрибуты, которые вы добавили в `__init__`.

Answer (score 2):

Как же невидно?

Вы сам видели, что `print(dir(a))` вывел на экран тоже ваш атрибут `wrong`, и когда вы добавите команду

```
print(a.wrong)
```

вы получите на экране

> ```
> Меня не видно внутри Meta
> ```

Comment: Вопрос то не про то, что атрибут не видно в экземпляре, а про то, что в верхний регистр не преобразует, если я правильно понял )  То есть метакласс этого атрибута `wrong` не видит.

Comment: @CrazyElf да, именно в этом вопрос